# explorer.exe and tskmngr.exe incredibly high memory usage

Tags: windows-xp, memory, task-manager, sp3

On start up, both explorer.exe and tskmgr.exe start increasing in mem usage up to 1GO and more  with high 100% CPU usage and the computer becomes very slow and un-usable.
This started to happen after formating the computer, installing windows xp + dell drivers + sp3.

Any idea how to fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you disabled and prevent all programs nor require during the startup procedure?

Comment: yes, disabled all non microsoft services on msconfig, on startup the CPU usage is 100 then the memory usage for explorer.exe starts to increase incredibly

Comment: What other tools have you used to determine which service is tasking your CPU?